# Частотный анализ

Tags: c#, алгоритм, криптография

Задача состоит в написании программы, которая дешифрует зашифрованный шифром подстановки текст. Насколько я понял, чтобы дешифровать текст, нужно произвести частотный анализ какого-либо крупного текста, определить вероятность каждой буквы. Затем произвести замену букв с наименьшей разностью в вероятностях.

- Каким образом можно создать идеальное соответствие букв из источника
  и зашифрованного текста, чтобы для каждой буквы зашифрованного
  символа находилась максимально приближённая по вероятности буква
  текста-источника?
- И в чём заключается двухсимвольный, трёхсимвольный и т.д. частотный
  анализ?
- Как лучше всего хранить данные в данной задаче?

Comment: Положение букв в словах так же очень важно, Русском языке около 14% слов начинаются на 'П', из которых половина на 'ПО'. Это по словарю, по реальному тексту смотреть надо. почитайте вот это для начала http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467831/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/467988#467988

Comment: А идеальное совпадение букв можно определить проверяя полученные слова по словарю

Comment: двух, трех и более символьный анализ собственно основан на распространенности определенных комбинаций букв. но тут надо привязываться к положению в слове. 'ее' может часто повторятся в конце Русских слов, но вряд ли попадется в начале

Comment: Идеальный? Никак. В зашифрованном тексте могут быть свои частоты. Не ленитесь, вам **придётся** подбирать руками.