# Дешифровка текста (частотный анализ)

Tags: криптография, шифрование

**Есть зашифрованный текст:**
*щ ьфьъзеэ кщвъязфхъзкд нэок амфопф адеа нзъч. аф-амътзъьс ф нъхсогъ зъ иупф хъщеъч. нфь бэчхфмфзщгфбф афбмсякпщд х емэсм – аъмщфзэп амкекй, эзбъпкзэ йфнкпэ ипънзэд к щ яэапэгэззуьк бпэяэьк, хкзкпэ щъид. йфядкз яэаъмщд х гэикзъеъ к амэгеквъщгк фееснэ зъ хуйфнкп. яэимфщкп мэифес, фе ъну фегэяухэпщд, фщсзспщд, щаэп щ пкцэ.
– эмесм, еу иу афъп веф-зкисна? – сьфпдшыъ афамфщкпэ эзбъпкзэ. – к амъгмэек гсмкеа, щгфпагф ьфтзф! нхъ аэвгк хущьфпкп! – фзэ хумхэпэ с зъбф кя аэпацъх щкбэмъес, яэесокпэ х аъаъпазкцъ, мэщаэйзспэ оефму к фегмупэ фгзф х гэикзъеъ, хасщекх х гфьзэес щфпзцъ к аъзкъ аекц.
бэчхфмфзщгкч сбмшьф афщьфемъп зэ бсхъмзэзегс, нфщеэп кя аэвгк нмсбсш щкбэмъес, амкгсмкп к щзфхэ соъп х щъид.
– эмесм, хфяаьк щъид х мсгк, въме хфяаьк! х ифпазкцэй к ьфмбэй нэок зъе. еу тъ щэь бфхфмкп, веф нэогэ иъбсзад. фзэ хъмзъещд, фидяэеъпазф хъмзъещд! – эзбъпкзэ физдпэ ьствкзс щяэнк яэ апъвк к амктэпэща ыъгфч г ъбф яэеупгс.
х гэикзъе яэбпдзспэ бфмзквзэд к нфпфткпэ:
– г хэь кхэз эмгэнаъхкв.
бэчхфмфзщгкч хдпф гкхзсп.
хэмпэьфх хфоъп х гфьзэес ифнмфч афйфнгфч.
– зъ афзкьэш д хэоъ сафмзфъ зътъпэзкъ фимэекеащд х ькпкцкш, – щгэяэп фз. – ъщпк иу нэмаш афйкекпк щ цъпаш хугсаэ, еф нэхзф иу афяхфзкпк к сщпфхкд хущеэхкпк. афмэ афнгпшвкеа амэхффймэзкеъпазуъ фмбэзу.
– зъзэхктс ьъзефх. ьфд щпстиэ иъяфаэщзфщек нъпэъе хщъ хфяьфтзфъ.
– асщеа амфнфптэъе х ефь тъ нсйъ. хэщ зкгеф к зъ амфщке пшикеа ьъзефх, афнсьэчеъ ф нфвъмк – афмэ афнгпшвэеа нфафпзкеъпазуъ мъяъмху, к д язэш въпфхъгэ, гфефмуч щьфтъе зэь афьфва. щфикмэчеъща, иснс тнэеа хэщ х ьэокзъ. нфхфпазф нсмэгэ хэпдеа!
хэмпэьфх хуоъп яэ нхъма. бэчхфмфзщгкч мэянэхкп фгсмфг х аъаъпазкцъ к ьънпъззф афнздпщд.*

**Провел его частотный анализ в Excel-е, получил частоты букв. Стоит упомянуть, что знаки препинания и пробелы не кодировались. Слева частоты в текущем тексте, справа данные с Википедии**

[image: Частоты]
**Прямая замена символов по приблизительным частотам ничего не дает, видимо, текст слишком маленький, получается что-то непонятное. В то же время почти уверен, что Ф -> О. Если кто-то сможет подсказать, то буду очень благодарен.**

Comment: Вы вообще уверены, что текст зашифрован с использованием просто иного алфавита? Если это уже даже виженер, то частотный анализ ничего не даст

Comment: В общем, если не найдёте разгадку - вечером посмотрю. Любил я в молодости шифры создавать/решать

Comment: Для остальных: не надо закрывать вопрос. Он затрагивает тему алгоритмов и шифрования, так что к нашей основной теме все же отношение имеет.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, о шифре, честно говоря, мне ничего не известно. Задание выдал преподаватель, он уверял, что разгадать можно именно частотным анализом. Благодарю за отклик, пока буду сам думать, с ходу вот не получилось пока. Потом напишу программу, но сначала хотелось бы разобраться.

Comment: В таких делах стоит начать с очень маленьких слов (читать - с предлогов). Посмотрите на отдельно стоящие буквы. `щ`, `ф`, `к`, `х`. Попробуйте по частотной таблице найти ближайшие к ним буквы, которые могут играть у нас роль предлогов. Потом подставить их в текст и идти дальше. Возможно, постепенно прояснится

Comment: И ещё одно: в результирующем тексте ни разу не встречается буква `ё`. Возможно, ей заменили какую-то очень редкую букву, которая реально не встретилась в тексте. А возможно, ее попросту нет в алфавите, то есть используется 32-буквенный русский алфавит (без `ё` как в исходном, так и в результирующем тексте). Посмотрите частотную таблицу для такового алфавита

Comment: `щгэяэп фз` == `сказал он`. Мои глаза выхватили из контекста. 7 букв Вам в копилку)

Comment: Ахахах, отлично, поздравляю)

Comment: На самом деле текст для анализа просто огромный. Тут действительно частотного отдельных букв вполне должно хватать, если понимать самое главное - частоты лишь примерный показатель, аналитик все равно должен смотреть на текст и думать какой вариант где может подойти. Ну и не забывать, что часто стоит смотреть частоты букв или их сочетаний в конкретных местах слов. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/467831/194569

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С момента исчезновения Даши прошло пять дней. По-прежнему о девушке не было вестей. Дом Гайворонского погрузился в траур – персонал притих, Ангелина ходила бледная и с заплаканными глазами, винила себя. Хозяин заперся в кабинете и практически оттуда не выходил. Забросил работу, от еды отказывался, осунулся, спал с лица.

– Артур, ты бы поел что-нибудь? – умоляюще попросила Ангелина. – И прекрати курить, сколько можно! Две пачки высмолил! – Она вырвала у него из пальцев сигарету, затушила в пепельнице, распахнула шторы и открыла окно в кабинете, впустив в комнату солнце и пение птиц.

Гайворонский угрюмо посмотрел на гувернантку, достал из пачки другую сигарету, прикурил и снова ушел в себя.

– Артур, возьми себя в руки, черт возьми! В больницах и моргах Даши нет. Ты же сам говорил, что Дашка бегунья. Она вернется, обязательно вернется! – Ангелина обняла мужчину сзади за плечи и прижалась щекой к его затылку.

В кабинет заглянула горничная и доложила:

– К вам Иван Аркадьевич.

Гайворонский вяло кивнул.

Варламов вошел в комнату бодрой походкой.

– Не понимаю я ваше упорное нежелание обратиться в милицию, – сказал он. – Если бы Дарью похитили с целью выкупа, то давно бы позвонили и условия выставили. Пора подключить правоохранительные органы.

– Ненавижу ментов. Моя служба безопасности делает все возможное.

– Пусть продолжает в том же духе. Вас никто и не просит любить ментов, подумайте о дочери – пора подключать дополнительные резервы, и я знаю человека, который сможет нам помочь. Собирайтесь, буду ждать вас в машине. Довольно дурака валять!

Варламов вышел за дверь. Гайворонский раздавил окурок в пепельнице и медленно поднялся.

[image: Замены]

Все расшифровывается, как и писали в комментариях:
1) Проводим частотный анализ, находим самую часто встречающуюся букву
2) Заменяем эту букву на "О"
3) Ищем слова: "он, она, они, кто, что, то" и находим остальные буквы.